# Linux Centos 5.5 yum update command is not working

Tags: linux, updates, yum

I have done lots of things to update.

```
yum clean all.
yum clean metadata
yum clean dbcache
```

then ...

```
yum update
```

but the output is:

> http://mirror.centos.org/centos/5.6/addons/i386/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 14] HTTP Error 404: Not Found
>   Trying other mirror.
>
> Error: Cannot retrieve repository metadata (repomd.xml) for repository: addons. Please verify its path and try again

I have done also:

`vi /etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS-Media.repo`

Modify it to `enabled=0`

But the same.  :(

I have done this too:

```
yum -v update --disablerepo=contrib
uname -a
```

The same

I have done again another way... like...

```
touch /.autorelabel

yum -v update --disablerepo=contrib
```

What should i do????Give me some answer :(  :( please.

Comment: Should be moved to http://unix.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Matten @ Thanks that solved the problem ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you open the link, you get a 404 error, which is exactly what `yum` told you.

If you go down the tree until http://mirror.centos.org/centos/5.6/, you can see a readme:

> This directory (and version of CentOS) is depreciated.  For normal users,
>   you should use /5/ and not /5.6/ in your path. Please see this FAQ
>   concerning the CentOS release scheme:
>
> http://www.centos.org/modules/smartfaq/faq.php?faqid=34
>
> If you know what you are doing, and absolutely want to remain at the 5.6
>   level, go to http://vault.centos.org/ for packages. Please keep in mind that 5.6 no
>   longer gets any updates

You should check how to upgrade to a newer version.

Comment: Thanks all my problem with analysis of my yum.repos.d :)If anyone need the answer I'll help.Thanks for your answer @wormsparty